# Creating multiple columns in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am reasonably familiar with dplyr, but am stuck in the following issue. I have the following table.

```
Issue      Rejected Accepted

Issue 1    2        4
Issue 2    3        6
Issue 3    0        1
```

What I want to do is create a new column(Decision) which will have the accept and reject as the entries. So what I want to do is change it to the following,

```
Issue   Decision    Quantity

Issue 1 Rejected    2
Issue 1 Accepted    4
Issue 2 Rejected    3
Issue 2 Accepted    6
Issue 3 Rejected    0
Issue 3 Accepted    1
```

Comment: You need the `reshape`. Try something like `reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "Issue")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- gather(df, Issue)
colnames(df1)[2:3] <- c("Decision", "Quantity") 

df1 %>% arrange(Issue)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!